# Injection of Repository into ShellViewModel, via Bootstrapper OnStartUp

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm stuck!

I'm using `Caliburn.micro` to take away some of the pain implementing `MVVM` in a `WPF` application.

Currently I only have a single View / ViewModel, but in the future there could be several ViewModels. The current ViewModel is using a Repository to populate a list of objects:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{

    private IMyObjectRepository<IMyObject> _myObjectsRepo = null;
    private BindableCollection<MyObject> _myObjects;
    private string _connString;


    /// <summary>
    /// constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        //call the method which sets up the repository
        GetMyObjectsRepository();

        //following three lines cast the list from type IReport to type Report
        var IMyObjects= _myObjectsRepo.GetAllIMyObjects();
        var myObjects = IMyObjects.OfType<MyObject>().ToList();
        MyObjects = new BindableCollection<MyObject>(myObjects );
    }

    private void GetMyObjectsRepository()
    {
        _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
        _myObjectRepo = MyObjectRepositoryFactory.InstantiateRepo(_connString);
    }
```

The above smells like a future problem - if I create a different ViewModel which has its own attribute of `BindableCollection<MyObject> _myObjects;` then the  two collections, of the same objects, could quickly have different states i.e. ObjectX in the first ViewModel might change its name attribute, but ObjectX still has its original name in the second ViewModel.

I was thinking I could inject this list of `<MyObject>` into the ViewModel when it is constructed - should I do this in `Bootstrapper.cs`? (I'd rather avoid full blown DI as this is a small project)

Currently `Bootstrapper.cs` looks like the following  - how do I move some of the logic in the above code snippet into here? Does it go in the `OnStartUp` event method? If so then how?

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Prototype_WPF.ViewModels;
using System.Windows;

namespace Prototype_WPF
{
    public class Bootstrapper: BootstrapperBase
    {

        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your problem.. you want to have more ShellviewModel/Shellview ? if yes how you plan to display the View?

Comment: @Frenchy thanks for comment - I'm really really new to MVVM and Caliburn so please excuse naivety of question.
I'd potentially want more ViewModels in the future and am worried that the list `private BindableCollection<MyObject> _myObjects` will need to be repeated in the new ViewModels.... is this not a problem?

Comment: If you want to synchronize the list, you could use eventAggregator to publish an event..but without more code its difficult to answer to your question...i dont know the logic of your program, how you display the view or you select the view you want to display....i could help you but need to have more code or a project..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Handler` method to register factory methods for your view models in the bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private readonly BindableCollection<MyObject> _myObjects = new BindableCollection<MyObject>();
    private SimpleContainer container;

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new SimpleContainer();
        container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        container.Handler<ShellViewModel>(_ => new ShellViewModel(_myObjects));
        container.Handler<SomeOtherViewModel>(_ => new SomeOtherViewModel(_myObjects));
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor(typeof(ShellViewModel));
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you. Apart from adding an argument into my view model constructor will I need to alter any other classes?

Comment: @whytheq: No, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason for the extra methods such as GetAllInstances? Is that just boilerplate I need to include? (I'm finding the Caliburn docs a little too technical at this point so any light you can shed would be appreciated)

Comment: These implementations make sure that you (or the framework) are resolving the types using the container that you create and set up in `Configure()`.

Comment: this framework is very powerful. One more question: apart from the Caliburn docs do you know of any other good resources i'd be adviced to use?

Comment: @whytheq: Not apart from the actual source code on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate component for retrieving your objects, something like `IMyObjectService` and implement it.

```
public interface IMyObjectService
{
     IList<MyObject> GetMyObjects();
}
```

Than create an overload of `Configure` method in `Bootstrapper` and register an implementation, something like that:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
      container = new SimpleContainer();

      container.Singleton<IMyObjectService, MyObjectService>();
      //other registrations
      container.PerRequest<ShellViewModel>();
}
```

And finally use a constructor injection for any ViewModel to inject and use this service. The `Caliburn.Micro` documentation already has some [examples](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper)

Answer (score 1):

You can 'Register' the service and 'Register' every class like below

```
protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new SimpleContainer();

        container.Instance(container);

        container
            .Singleton<IMyObjectService, MyObjectService>();

        //Register all ViewModel classes            
        GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass)
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(viewModleType => container.RegisterPerRequest(
                viewModleType, viewModleType.ToString(), viewModleType));

    }
```